# Slickgrid resize works in Firefox, doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: slickgrid

When I resize the column in Chrome, the screen freezes for 20 ~ 30 seconds. In Firefox, this doesn't happen.

I'm using slickgrid v2.0 alpha from Github.

```
<!--- JQUERY -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

On my workstation I have Chrome 17.0.963.83 m and on the workstations with issues I have Chrome 6.0.495.0 m. I upgraded one of the workstations to the newest version of Chrome and I can't resize the collumns, it freezes up for 20 ~ 30 seconds.

I'm wondering what tests can I do to find out what is wrong, I don't see any errors in Javascript Console or anything else.

Thanks.

**LATER EDIT**

I'm initializing my grid as following

```
    // additional options
var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false, 
    showHeaderRow: true, 
    editable:true, 
    asyncEditorLoading: false, 
    autoEdit:true,
    defaultColumnWidth:90
};
```

And I'm not sure if this code affects the resize plugin

```
    // header code
    grid.onColumnsResized.subscribe(function (e, args) {

      updateHeaderRow();

      $('#pager').html("Count : " + grid.getDataLength());

    });
```

Please don't ask why I'm not using the Dataview method provided with Slickgrid.

Comment: Please include a jsfiddle.net repro case.

Comment: can't do that unfortunately... but I can edit my post and show you pieces of code

Comment: did tests on the faulty Chrome clients and they behave normally with examples from the developer, it seems there is a problem with my code, further tests required. unfortunately, no errors are generated, only the screen freezes up.

Comment: the solution was to upgrade the Chrome client to the latest version on faulty workstations, no coding errors whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to upgrade the Chrome client to the latest version on faulty workstations, no coding errors whatsoever